Trying to calculate certain values within a buffered zone, but entire region is counted instead in GEE
I'm trying to calculate coral cover within a certain buffer zone, however, when I try to calculate this, the area of the entire buffered zone is counted. I have managed to split the two areas into masked and unmasked, but cannot separate them during this final step. I'm using GEE.
My code is:
var coral_area = newvalues
    .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
    .reduceRegions({
         reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
         collection: buffered_stations,
         scale: 5
    });

I have tried:
var coral_area = newvalues.
    .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().selfMask())
    .reduceRegions({
         reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
         collection: buffered_stations,
         scale: 5
    });

but this does not fix the issue. Any help?

Is newvalues definitely an image with only 0 (mask) or 1 (coral)? If so, the first solution looks correct.
